# Blank Page on first load of an user

Tags: php, mysql

I get a blank page on the first load every time. This only happens if the visitor('s ip) isn't in the database yet.

These are also errors I receive, I've also tried deleting the lines to see if the issue lies in there. :

Notice: Undefined index: ref in /home/***/public_html/share2.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: us in /home/***/public_html/share2.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined index: ns in /home/***/public_html/share2.php on line 34

Deprecated: Function sql_regcase() is deprecated in /home/***/public_html/share2.php on line 38

Deprecated: Function sql_regcase() is deprecated in /home/***/public_html/share2.php on line 45

Deprecated: Function sql_regcase() is deprecated in /home/***/public_html/share2.php on line 52

```
//MySQL Connect
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<!-- MySQL connected -->";

//Initialize functions
function RandomString() {
    $length = 15;
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $string = "";    
    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand (0, strlen ($characters))];
    }
    return $string;
}
echo "<!-- Randomstring function loaded -->";

//Get inurl variables
$refid = $_GET['ref'];
$updateskin = $_GET['us'];
$newskin = $_GET['ns'];
echo "<!-- Inurl vars have been retrieved -" . $refid . ", " . $updateskin . ", " . $newskin . " -->";

//Make sure $refid is clean
$refid = preg_replace(sql_regcase("/(from|select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables|#|\*|--|\\\\)/"),"",$refid); 
$refid = trim($refid); 
$refid = strip_tags($refid); 
$refid = addslashes($refid); 
echo "<!-- Refid cleaned - " . $refid . " -->";

//Make sure $updateskin is clean
$updateskin = preg_replace(sql_regcase("/(from|select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables|#|\*|--|\\\\)/"),"",$updateskin); 
$updateskin = trim($updateskin); 
$updateskin = strip_tags($updateskin); 
$updateskin = addslashes($updateskin); 
echo "<!-- updateskin cleaned - " . $updateskin . " -->";

//Make sure $newskin is clean
$newskin = preg_replace(sql_regcase("/(from|select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables|#|\*|--|\\\\)/"),"",$newskin); 
$newskin = trim($newskin); 
$newskin = strip_tags($newskin); 
$newskin = addslashes($newskin); 
echo "<!-- newskin cleaned - " . $newskin . " -->";


//Client data
$clientip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$clientbrowser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$clientrefurl = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
echo "<!-- Retrieved servervars -->";

//Check if ip is already in database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ref WHERE ip = '$clientip'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<!-- IP check query-->";

//Prevent the script from failing if there was a MySQL error
if ( false === $result ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    echo "<!-- MYSQL ERROR -->";
}

//Check number of results to see if they IP is already in the db
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

//If the IP is not in the database yet
if ($numrows == 0)
{
$id = RandomString();
$ip = $clientip;
$hits = 0;
$firsthitdate = date("d-m-Y H:i:s"); 
$browser = $clientbrowser;
$refurl = $clientrefurl;
$sql = "INSERT INTO ref (id, ip, hits, firsthitdate, browser, refurl) VALUES('$id', '$ip', '$hits', '$firsthitdate', '$browser', '$refurl')";
$result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());


if (isset($refid) === false)
{
$refid = "noref";
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ref WHERE id = '$refid'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
$hits = $data['hits'];
$hits = $hits +1;
$sql = "UPDATE ref SET hits = '$hits' WHERE id = '$refid'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
$hits = 0;
}

//If they IP is already in the database
if ($numrows == 1)
{
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ref WHERE ip = '$clientip'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
$id = $data['id'];
$hits = $data['hits'];
}

//Change skin if required
if ($updateskin == 1)
{
$sql = "UPDATE ref SET skinname = '$newskin', skinselect = '1' WHERE id = '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
}

//Get from database if there has been a skin selected already
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ref WHERE ip = '$clientip'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
$skinselect = $data['skinselect'];
$skinname = $data['skinname'];
```

Comment: your GET variables aren't set check them again...are they getting any value using isset() fuction then assign them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

to print out the array of the get vars.

The errors are you have mentioned are regarding the calls to the $_GET when is isn't present.

Use isset method https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php to check before trying to use something that's not set